# Live Server Custom page block not appearing

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, custom, page

I know this question already asked, but still i can't solve my problem.

I have creating `front-end` & `back-end` custom pages. The code working in `local server`. But same code not working in `Live Server`.

**My codes are following:**

`\app\code\local\EPayment\EPayment\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EPayment_EPayment>
            <version>0.1.0</version>

        </EPayment_EPayment>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <epayment>
            <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>EPayment_EPayment</module>
                    <frontName>epayment</frontName>
                </args>
            </epayment>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <epayment>
                <file>epayment.xml</file>
                </epayment>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <epayment>
                <class>EPayment_EPayment_Helper</class>
            </epayment>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <epayment>
                <class>EPayment_EPayment_Block</class>
            </epayment>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <epayment>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                <module>EPayment_EPayment</module>
                <frontName>admin_epayment</frontName>
                </args>
            </epayment>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <epayment>
                    <file>epayment.xml</file>
                </epayment>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

`\app\code\local\EPayment\EPayment\etc\adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
      <epayment module="epayment">
        <title>EPayment</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <epaymentbackend module="epayment">
            <title>EPayment</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend</action>
          </epaymentbackend>
        </children>
      </epayment>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <epayment translate="title" module="epayment">
              <title>EPayment</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <epaymentbackend translate="title">
            <title>EPayment</title>
          </epaymentbackend>
              </children>
            </epayment>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\epayment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <epayment_adminhtml_epaymentbackend_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend" name="epaymentbackend_index" template="epayment/epaymentbackend.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </epayment_adminhtml_epaymentbackend_index>

    <epayment_adminhtml_epaymentbackend_history>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend" name="epaymentbackend_history" template="epayment/history.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </epayment_adminhtml_epaymentbackend_history>

</layout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a block permission problem. To add your custom block's permission:

- Go to **`System > Permissions > Blocks`**.
- Click on **`Add New Block`** button.
- Add your block's name in the **Block Name** field and set **`Yes`** for **Is Allowed** field.
- Click **`Save Block`** button and flush Magento cache.

Now please check the page where the block should be rendered.

If the problem still exists, please check Magento log files as well as server's Apache error logs for more clues.

Comment: I have create new block permission and clear cache still empty check this link https://ibb.co/e0fg9m

Comment: This is the block name right  `epaymentbackend_index`

Comment: And i check `error_log` also no error found.

Comment: block name to be permitted should be epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend

Comment: Changed  to `epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend` still empty bro

Comment: I think i did small mistake in `epayment.xml`

Answer (score 0):

in your `config.xml` define router this way

```
 <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <epayment before="Mage_Adminhtml">EPayment_EPayment</epayment>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

in your `adminhtml.xml` file action node should be

```
        <action>adminhtml/epaymentbackend/index</action>
```

in your `epayment.xml` file change handler

from

```
   <epayment_adminhtml_epaymentbackend_index>
```

TO

```
    <adminhtml_epaymentbackend_index>
```

Comment: Bro thanks for your code page showing 404 page

Comment: Bro page showing 404 error ?